# How can I combine a Strike and a Stride?

Tags: optimization, actions, pathfinder-2e

Rangers can use the Skirmish Strike to Step and Strike. Most enemies however don't do you a favor and stand just 5 feet away after you killed one of their friends.

What is the lowest investment for a  Ranger to get such an action without homebrew?

Comment: Melee Rangers frequently have this issue: no enemy in reach (mostly because the adjacent one just died), so you need one action to Stride, one to Hunt Prey, one to Command your Animal, and one to actually deal damage... oh wait! I consider this a design error, ranged Rangers and melee Fighters do not have this problem.

Comment: I don't understand the point of the rant... Paizo seems to feel that it was a reasonable accommodation that you have trouble getting into melee but can get an Animal Companion (eventually with a free action while your Hunt Prey is active) and other supportive features.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here? Also, in your comment - why do you feel the need to both Command your Animal and Hunt Prey every turn?

Comment: @indigochild switching target leaves Barbarians, melee Fighters and archer Rangers with two remaining actions, but melee Rangers have only one. This makes them close to unviable.

Comment: I guess I don't see how the loss of one action (of three) on changing targets in situations where Hunt Prey is beneficial and you have a second creature in your control (that effectively adds one action when used) makes a build "unviable". Yes, you are giving up some melee ability to have an Animal Companion. That's a choice you make. You *can* choose *not* to take Animal Companion and have just as many effective actions as Fighters, Barbarians, and ranged Rangers.

Comment: Notably, the first line of the class's combat flavor is "You can single out particular foes to hunt [...] You target and brutalize your chosen foe..." I wouldn't expect Paizo to quickly release a method to make fighting multiple targets easier as a Ranger.

Comment: If it helps, the Hunter's Edge class feature choices are generally stronger than the baked-in strength of Fighters, and easily rival the Barbarian Instinct choices without the obvious drawbacks... although, if I may say something. You seem to have a distaste for the Ranger class. It might not be the right choice *for you*.

Comment: @Ifusaso it is not the right choice for anyone who wants to be effective in melee no matter the enemy compositon. I agree it is good (probably even better than a Fighter) against a boss, but so is an archer Ranger. And you cannot pick the encounters, unless you are the DM.

Comment: Well I wasn't looking to start a debate. I don't see the weakness that you seem to. On paper, a ranged build probably does beat it by a small amount numerically, but I don't consider it statistically relevant. I was only intending to suggest that maybe you just don't go with that build (or do and accept that your damage will sometimes not be the highest at the table).

Comment: @Ifusaso some people did not see the weakness of Monks in DnD 3.5. It doesn't mean it wasn't there.

Comment: Some people like to play a character instead of a number. /thread

Comment: @Ifusaso "I don't understand the point of the rant" - sorry but overcoming limitations is a legitimate part of character optimization. If you don't like [tag:optimization] questions, maybe this tag is simply not for you? Adding tags to ignored is easy enough, and your comments looks like a rant that some people optimize :(

Comment: @Mołot, partially my fault, I just added the `optimization` tag a few minutes ago. I thought it was clear this was an optimization related question.

Comment: @András I feel you on the target switching as a ranger, but in single target melee rangers do really shine. In the situation you described it would be better to just attack yourself instead of commanding your animal, pet attacks just do not hit as hard as the ranger themselves will. also by the time fighters and rogues get the capability to stride and step (with limitations) your hunt prey makes commanding your pet a free action. I don't think this limitation at lower levels makes this class/play-style close to not being viable (especially when compared to 3.5's monk)

Comment: I appreciate the need to optimize, and I can see the question better in that context. I regularly make optimization builds for fun. I don't then compare them to a Wizard because why would I do anything other than Gate in a Solar. My original intent was more of a frame challenge "if you're building for X *and* Y, one or both portions of the build will suffer" but that doesn't *actually* answer the question.

Comment: Ofc Captain Obvious said it better than I could. Obviously =P

Comment: @CaptianObvious, I agree that in theoretical one-on-one melee Rangers outperform Fighters. However, in most (read 95+%) encounters there are more than one enemy, and they are further away from each other. Also, focus fire is the best tactic, as in most RPGs, so it is all the more likely that you _will_ have to change targets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## You can Stride and Strike, but only indirectly

If you *ride* your Animal Companion, you can use one action (Command an Animal) to get close to the next enemy, and then attack it.

Until 6th level, this only works with a Horse, all other animal companions are too small to be ridden.
Then, with the Mature Animal Companion feat other animals become Medium, so a small Ranger can ride anything.
Medium Rangers need need to wait until level 10, the Incredible Companion feat (and pick Savage) to get a large mount.

From level 6, you do not even need to spend an action to Command your companion, it will approach your Prey on its own.

Answer (score 12):

**This option is not available to Rangers**

The Fighter's [Spring Attack](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=413) and the Rogue's [Spring from the Shadows](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=586) allow you to stride and strike with one action, but these are not available to Rangers.

Comment: Good catch, I guess my search skills failed me. It may be worth noting that both of those Feats are 12th level, for some indication of the value weighted to that benefit.

Comment: It is unfortunate that the class that needs it most does not get it.

Comment: @András Please do note the requirements of these feats: The fighter is required to be adjacent to a (not slain) foe in order to stride to and strike another enemy, while the rouge feat do require you to be hidden from your foe, before you can stride and strike. These instances are quite situational and unless other feats would allow the fighter or rogue to get into position and strike with a single action, your point in the OP discussion, that ranger also needs this could be invalid.

Comment: @KasperThystrupKarstensen, you are right, the melee Ranger needs _better_, because unlike any other build in the game, he needs to spend 2 actions to change targets.

Comment: Oh yeah Spring Attack is a Press, so you have to have already attacked. Although the target *could* be knocked out by your first (or second if you were already next to them) Strike.

Comment: @András Because Rangers aren't made to change targets freely. They get a bunch of boons for focusing on attacking a single target. If they could swap targets as easily as a Fighter, the two classes would overlap more, which isn't desirable. Note that the time other classes get a conditional "Stride+Strike", Rangers have a feat to designate 2 hunted prey at once, which gives you at least 1 free target swap every fight with no extra action investment (and potentially other bigger things depending on Edge).

Comment: @András I'm sorry, I was not attempting to support your claim of the ranger needing a stride and strike action, I don't have an opinion on that matter. I was kindly trying to point out that the two features stated in this answer is very situational, and therefore doesn't support your claim strongly :(

Comment: @Delioth no one is talking about "_freely_". A feat on level 12 is typical case of too little too late.

Comment: @KasperThystrupKarstensen, my position is that Paizo estimated the usual situation badly, in 99% percent of the encounters melee Rangers perform way below other melee types or archer Rangers. Your comment just confirms that they made this mistake _consistently_.

Answer (score 6):

### There is currently no method to Stride and Strike as one Action.

<s>No class has the capability to Stride and Strike as one Action</s>For Rangers, there is currently no method to Stride and Strike as one Action, although the precedent does exist beginning around level 12; there is no spell that allows this either (although Quickening effects such as [Haste](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=147) may give a bonus Action that you could do one or the other with).

Fighters and Barbarians have the level 1 Feat Sudden Charge which costs 2 Actions to perform 2 Strides and a Strike. If this appeals to you, it is available through their [Class Archetypes](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx). This would cost 2 Class Feats (one requiring level 2 and the other level 4); they are the respective [Dedication](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=671) and [Basic](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=673) (Rage/Maneuver) Feats.

Comment: You might want to add that "_for Rangers_ 
[t]here is currently no method to Stride and Strike as one Action."

Comment: Yeah that's a good point. I wasn't looking to "take back" the answer from Strill, but I was going to leave it up because I do feel like my answer adds something for others coming to look at the question.